# Botão do Twitter não lê #

Tags: html, blogger, twitter-api

Meu blog tem o botão de tweet que funciona normalmente como qualquer outro: ele recebe o título da página e URL através de do data:post.title / data:post.url, respectivamente. O problema é que há alguns dias atrás, eu adicionei um # e o número do post nos títulos. Por exemplo, o título do texto de número 129 era "Kernel" e, em seguida, eu mudei para "#129 Kernel" (sem as aspas) e depois disso, o botão de tweet não lê o # que está no título do post e nada que vem após ele. Eu percebi que se eu substituir o # por % 23 ele funciona perfeitamente, mas há alguma maneira de fazer essa substituição automaticamente, sem renomear todas as postagens e tirar o # dos títulos?

Link da publicação: http://einconformado.blogspot.com/2015/06/kernel.html

Desde já, agradeço a gentileza. 
Deus abençoe! =]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: [Edite](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/192024/edit) sua pergunta e adicione os códigos responsáveis por gerar esse botão, assim ficará possível te ajudar.

Comment: Você tem razão, Anderson. A questão é que estou no celular agora e estou sem o fonte acessível aqui. O máximo que consegui no momento foi uma captura do trecho do código direto da interface do Blogger, que acrescentei à pergunta.

Comment: Então estranhe se sua pergunta for fechada em breve, mas não se preocupe, ela poderá ser reaberta quando você conseguir editar a pergunta devidamente.